# DataGrid in VS2008

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

There is not Datagrid in VS2008.
Did it get killed and replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinForm: DataGridView
ASP.NET: GridView

Comment: I dont see a DataGrid in my VS2008 ASP.Net toolbox
Is it called GridView in 2008?

Comment: Yes, It's called GridView in 2008.